# Firefox Extension To Save To Folder Named After Text On Webpage

Tags: regex, firefox, tags, directory, browser-addons

I am wanting to find or create a Firefox Extension that can create and save to a folder, based upon the text in a page's tag.

I would want it to do the following:

```
a. Check the page's html for a certain tag name (e.g. <itemName>), 
b. Use a regular expression to look for a text pattern within the tag mentioned above (e.g. first and last name like - <itemName>Abe Lincoln</itemName>),
c. Compare that pattern to folders already existing on the computer,
     c-i. If the folder exists, then just save the file (from a certain domain, in certain tag, etc) from the page to that folder,
     c-ii. If the folder does not exist, then create it and then save the aforementioned file from the page to that folder.

d. Close the page/tab.
```

I've been scouring the web for something like this, but as of yet, I haven't found something that can do this.  Is there something like this?
If not, is it possible to create an Extension that can work with Regular Expressions, like I need?

Thanks for your help in this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if there is an existing extension that doing this, but yes you can easily use regular expressions in a firefox extension where firefox extension uses javascript which support regular expressions

Developing a firefox extension is an easy task, you can search for tuts and here is a good one to begin with if you would like to

http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/

Also for sure you will need developer.mozilla for best details

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Building_an_Extension